# How to remove hover from Submit and Reset Button

Tags: html

What command do i need to use to don't make it zoom when i click "submit" or "reset" button. I want them just to look normal. i am supposed to use hover for this program but not for the last 2 buttons

Please see code below of what i have so far. anything is appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS rules</title>

    <style>
input:focus{
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 40px;
    width: 280px;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 24px;
}
input:hover{
    background-color: cyan;
    height: 40px;
    width: 280px;
    color: red;
    font-size: 24px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <form action="">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="LastName" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="FirstName"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>E-mail Address :</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" id="Email"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit"/>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="reset"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>
</body>
<!--body tag ends here-->
</html>
<!--html tag ends here-->
```

Tried playing with the code but i can't figure it out

Comment: Look normal in what way? You're specifically changing the way they look based on hover and focus.

Comment: Don't use `<input type="submit">`, use `<button type="submit">` instead (which in-turn means you'd have different selectors, thus avoiding this issue entirely). The `<input type="submit">` element is essentially and entirely obsolete at this point, the only reason to use it is if you need to support IE8.0 or older, which I'm sure you aren't doing.

Comment: Also, you should not be using just `input` as a selector, because the behaviour of style properties for `input[type=text]` are very different to `input[type=checkbox]`, for example (e.g. `border-style`, `background-color`, etc).

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS rules</title>

    <style>
input[type="text"]:hover, input[type="password"]:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 40px;
    width: 280px;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 24px;
}
input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus {
    background-color: cyan;
    height: 40px;
    width: 280px;
    color: red;
    font-size: 24px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <form action="">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="LastName" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="FirstName"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>E-mail Address :</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" id="Email"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit"/>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="reset"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>
</body>
<!--body tag ends here-->
</html>
<!--html tag ends here-->
```

Changed the way you call the style. By passing in the [type=text] in CSS, you make sure that only type=text and type=password pick up the styles, and making the submit and the reset button not pick up the styles.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add default style for when it's not hovering or in focus.  Try adding this to your the area between your `style` tags:

```
input {
    background-color: black;
    height: 40px;
    width: 280px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

If that's not what you intended, Yash Digant Joshi may have a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add hover effect on `input` which is not `submit` or `reset`.

```
:where(input:not([type="submit"]):not([type="reset"])):hover
```